# Why would someone sell stock at 52 week low?

Tags: stock-markets

I am interested to know why would someone sell their stocks at 52 week lows?

Comment: The question as asked is opinion based. Generally at any point in time there are people who believe the stock will go down and want to exit and some who believe the stock will go up and want to buy.

Comment: They might need the money and have no alternative.

Comment: @TripleHound that is an acceptable answer. But in general such volumes of trade is low, because of two reasons 1. They would only sell the stocks for the current need and not all the stocks are sold. 2. Most of the traders may not be in such a need in the first place.

Comment: The could be thinking that this will not be the next 52 week low, that is it will go lower.  You are using an indicator of the past to predict the future, that does not always workout.

Comment: In late 2015, Bausch Health (formerly Valeant Pharmaceuticals) made a new 52 week low in the $120 area.  18 months or so later it made an all time low under $9.   It now trades for about $24.  Selling at the 52 week low of $120+ looks pretty smart today.

Comment: @Nujufas Re. (1) Their current need might be for all the stock they hold (and your question didn't specify whether or not someone sold _all_ their holding). Re. (2) Again, you asked about why one person might sell, not about "_all traders_". As you can see, there are many reasons why someone _might_ sell; some good (for a particular individual) and some you can't tell are good until much later (and you can see what the stock did next).

Comment: Today's 52-week low might be next year's 52-week high.

Comment: The fact that it is 52-weeks low is not that relevant. If there is news that the company is getting into real trouble, then you might want to sell stock, since it is possible that eventually the stock will be worthless.

Comment: Marrying Hope has led to owning a lot of wallpaper.

Comment: @BobBaerker Thank you for the example on Bausch Health. As far as I see from the comments, It is either: a) Liquidity needs b) They sell because they suspect the stock to fall further. I would like to know if anybody want to add more. Or maybe I am just answering the question to 'why would someone sell a stock?' rather than 'why sell at 52 week low?'

Comment: Other reasons for selling can include fear, cutting losses (trailing stop), peace of mind (can't take the pain anymore), tax loss harvesting, rebalancing, better investment opportunities elsewhere.  Investors should ask themselves (1) Why did you buy the stock? (2) What changed? (3)  Does that change affect reasons for owning the shares?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess would be that they think next week will be the real 52 week low.

In all seriousness sentiment is a great component of any organized market as well as people making all sorts of emotionally based choices. Be it FOMO(fear of missing out) when things are going upwards, or doomsday sell-offs when there's a correction(heavy or not).